Flink SQL Query optimization
I am trying to write a Flink SQL query using Tables API for batch processing:
String query =
    "WITH testDataEvents AS "
        + " (SELECT view1.field.subField AS values "
        + "FROM view1, view2 where view1.creativeId = view2.creativeId) "
    + "SELECT "
        + "view2.field6 AS field6, "
        + "testDataEvents.values AS testDataField "
        + "FROM view2, testDataEvents ";

After running the query I realize that this is basically a join of two tables for a simple task.
I tried to re-write this query but looks like Flink SQL says it is not a valid query as it throws $cor* variable error
String query = 
        + "SELECT "
            + "view2.field6 AS field6, "
            + "(SELECT view1.field.subField AS values FROM view1 where"
            + "view1.creativeId = view2.creativeId) AS testDataField "
            + "FROM view2 ";

Any suggestion on how to write an optimized query to avoid join.

It's not clear why you are including view2 in the query at all. Why isn't this just SELECT view1.field.subField AS values FROM view1? If you are joining with view2 in order to exclude cases where there's no matching row in view2, then you'll have to use a join, but otherwise, it seems unnecessary.

@DavidAnderson updated the query as I missed adding the view2 column which is why I will need view2.
